# Add YouTube formatting tag to embedded videos

Tags: wordpress, youtube

How do i add this formatting tag to all embedded YouTube videos in WordPress if the videos are not mine?

```
yt:stretch=16:9
```

I need to remove the black bars/frame but the videos are not mine to edit.

Comment: You can try to add `padding-top` to the video wrapper. `padding-top:56.25%`  results in 16:9 aspect ratio.

Comment: What video wrapper are you referring to?